# How to choose value from <ul> <li> tags using Selenium Java?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with one thing. I am doing two equations in https://web2.0calc.com/. First one 2+2 and assert it and second one 3+3 and assert it.

First equation is done fine and I check it using:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/p[1]"));
String title = element.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(title);
Assert.assertEquals(title, "4");
```

It is passed.

But in the second one I cannot use xpath again, because it still takes me to the 4..

How to do that?

The code is below:

```
<ul>
<li>
<p title="6" class="r">=&nbsp;6</p>
<p data-inp="3+3" title="3+3" class="l">3+3</p>
</li>

<li>
<p title="4" class="r">=&nbsp;4</p>
<p data-inp="2+2" title="2+2" class="l">2+2</p>
</li>

</ul>
```

Expect to localize element "title=6" and then use it to assert equation.

Answer (score 0):

In `assertEquals` method the expected value is the first argument.

**Code example:**

```
package tests;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

// custom class with driver init
import selenium.ChromeDriverSetup;

public class Web20calc extends ChromeDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // wrapped driver init
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://web2.0calc.com/");
        
        // cookie consent
        driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"precmpdialog\"]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button")).click();
        
        WebElement btn2 = driver.findElement(By.id("Btn2"));
        WebElement btn3 = driver.findElement(By.id("Btn3"));
        WebElement btnPlus = driver.findElement(By.id("BtnPlus"));
        WebElement btnCalc = driver.findElement(By.id("BtnCalc"));
        WebElement btnClear = driver.findElement(By.id("BtnClear"));        
        WebElement showHistory = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"hist\"]/button[2]"));
        
        btn2.click();
        btnPlus.click();
        btn2.click();
        btnCalc.click();
        
        btnClear.click();
        
        btn3.click();
        btnPlus.click();
        btn3.click();
        btnCalc.click();
        
        showHistory.click();
        
        Assert.assertEquals("= 6", getHistoryResult(driver, 0));
        Assert.assertEquals("= 4", getHistoryResult(driver, 1));
        Assert.assertEquals(null, getHistoryResult(driver, 2));

        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public static String getHistoryResult(WebDriver driver, Integer lineNumber) {
        String result = null;
        WebElement histframe = driver.findElement(By.id("histframe"));
        WebElement ul = histframe.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
        List<WebElement> lis = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        Integer lisSize = lis.size();
        if (lineNumber > lisSize - 1) {
            System.out.println("Linenumber " + lineNumber + " is out of range. Size of List is: " + lisSize);
        }
        else {
            WebElement li = lis.get(lineNumber);
            WebElement p = li.findElement(By.tagName("p"));
            result = p.getText();
            System.out.println("Result in line " + lineNumber + ": " + result);
        }
        return result;      
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 36109
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1681997766.849][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 112.
Dub 20, 2023 3:36:06 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Result in line 0: = 6
Result in line 1: = 4
Linenumber 2 is out of range. Size of List is: 2
```